# Pass Java Arraylist to native query of JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I have a list of id List so how can I pass it to a native query of JpaRepository? I found out some answers about use IN in SQL query, but it is not used with List as parameter. 
Example: I have a list of Task in database, I want to select all of tasks whose id is in the list. 
My code looks like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT i FROM Task i WHERE DATE(i.startTime) = DATE(?1)")
Page<Task> findTasksByAssigneeIdAndAndStartTime(Pageable pageable, List<Long> taskId, Timestamp today);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN with list as parameter. Like below.

```
 @Query(value="SELECT i FROM Task i WHERE DATE(i.startTime) = DATE(?1) and taskId in :taskId",nativeQuery = true)
 Page<Task> findTasksByAssigneeIdAndAndStartTime(Pageable pageable, List<Long> taskId, Timestamp today);
```

Comment: I got a problem with pageable here

Comment: Your query was how to pass list as parameter in native query which is given above in taskId. For the rest, you have to manipulate your code.